# Fetching location in the Background with Swift in IOS13

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, ios13, background-fetch

I'm kind of confused with the New BGTaskScheduler That we need to use in for IOS13.

Having an app that needs to get a user location in the BG and do some process with that location and send data to the server (If user permits) and i can't understand how to do it.

I've got to the point of:

1. Rergisturing the task:

```
    private func registerBackgroundTasks() {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier:"com.testdomain.BackgroundLocationFetch", using: nil) { task in
            self.handleBGLocationFetch(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
    }
```

2. creating the Scheduler:

```
   private func scheduleLocationFetch() {
           let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "com.testdomain.BackgroundLocationFetch")
           request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true
           request.requiresExternalPower = false

       // Fetch no earlier than 15 minutes from now
       request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60)

       do {
           try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)

       } catch {
           print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
       }
   }
```

3. Now in the handleBGLocationFetch method:

```
private func handleBGLocationFetch(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1


    task.expirationHandler = {
        // After all operations are canceled, the completion block is called to complete the task
        queue.cancelAllOperations()
    }

    queue.completionBlock {
        // Perform the task

        ***** DO I CALL THE fetchlocation method here and will i get the callback here? ******
        ***** What do i do with the task? Why do we need it? *****
        ??????
    }

    // Add the task to the queue
    queue.addOperation(????????)
}
```

I really got lost in this. Probably not the first or last one.

ps. Of course i'm calling the register in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and the scheduler method in applicationDidEnterBackground. Just so there wont be any misunderstanding.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use Apple's regular background location APIs that are available if your app has background location access?

Comment: I am, but I need to get a hourly location from the user even if he didn't move so send it to an api to get data on that location.
So I need to make a background fetch or a silent push notification and in the get location and, send post Http request.
When the user is moving it is not an issue. It is working great.

Comment: Is The issue solved? I also need the answer.